# Enum's String property used for Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, ejb

I would like to reuse safetype enum which I already have to specify argument for @Resource annotation which requires String compile time constant.
I have not found any elegant solution how to reuse DATASOURCE except this that I enclose:

```
public enum DATASOURCE {
  // Enum constants
  DataSource1, DataSource2;

  public final static String DataSource1_jndi = "java:/jdbc/DataSource1";
  public final static String DataSource2_jndi = "java:/jdbc/DataSource2";

  public String getJndiName() {
    switch(this) {
      case DataSource1:
        return DataSource1_jndi;
      case DataSource2:
        return DataSource2_jndi;
      default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Not defined jndi name for DATASOURCE " + this);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage of enum itself

```
public class DataSourceFactory {

  /**
   * @param ds Identifier of datasource
   */
  public static DataSource getDataSource(DATASOURCE ds) {
    // maybe some caching for datasource identified by constant
    ...
    return (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(ds.getJndiName());
  }
}
```

But now I would like to use the same DATASOURCE constant also in SessionBeans along with @Resource annotation

```
@Stateless
public class SomeSessionBean {
  // This is what I would love to use but 
  // annotation wants compile time constant :-(
  // @Resource(mappedName=DATASOURCE.DataSource1.getJndiName());
  @Resource(mappedName=DATASOURCE.DataSource1_jndi);
  DataSource ds;

  ... 
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's not a big deal, there is nothing wrong with the solution you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine as it is.

Comment: It's a pitty that miracles do not happen :-(
In our application we really have multiple datasources and using datasource name direcly written as literal into code is quite error prone.

Comment: I know how you feel. I was surprised about this (the requirement for a constant, not the miracles :-) ) as well when I first discovered it.

Comment: As miracle have not already happened, I consider your answer as solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply your enum a little though:

```
public enum DATASOURCE {
Datasource1("java:/jdbc/DataSource1"), Datasource2("java:/jdbc/DataSource2");
private String jndiReference;

private DATASOURCE(String jndiReference) {
    this.jndiReference = jndiReference;
}

public String getJndiName() {
    return this.jndiReference;
}
}
```

Comment: Even if you specify jndiReference as public final String jndiReference then in case you try to use @Resource(mappedName=DATASOURCE.Datasource1.jndiReference) in code compiler complains: "The value for annotation attribute Resource.mappedName must be a constant expression". Please do not erase your answer (even it solves the problem I am afraid) because this exact answer was here yesterday.